# React не удается настроить проброс данных при onClick ивенте с binf(this)

Tags: reactjs

Есть список с двумя вариантами контроллов: ссылка и li-кнопка. Нужно при нажатии прокинуть данные в `url` запроса к серверу и отобразить необходимую информацию в редакторе.

Также буду признателен, если кто-то подскажет, как сделать смену `url`'a при `onClick`.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        url: '',
        folders: [],
        currentTemplate: [],
        texttemps: [],
        text: '',
        loading: true
    };
    this.onChanged = this.onChanged.bind(this);


    fetch('здесь ссылка',
        {
            method: 'GET',
            Accept: 'application/json'

        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({ folders: data, loading: false });
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));

    fetch('здесь ссылка',
        {
            method: 'GET',
            Accept: 'application/json'

        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({ texttemps: data, loading: false });
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));

    if (this.state.url === undefined) {
        this.setState.currentTemplate = [{ id: -1, value: '' }]
    }
    else {
        fetch(this.state.url,
            {
                method: 'GET',
                Accept: 'application/json'

            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ currentTemplate: data })
            })
    }

}

onChanged = (state) => {
    this.setState(state)
}

static getTextTemplate(urlClick) {
    this.onChanged({ url: 'здесь ссылка/' + urlClick })
    return (
        <p>
            {
                this.state.currentTemplate.map(temp =>
                temp.value
            )
            }
        </p>

    );
}
static getFolders(folders, texttemps, key, lvl) {
    key = key + 1;
    lvl = lvl + 1;
    return (

        <ul style={styles.ul}>
            {folders.map(folder =>
                <li style={styles.li} className="Folder" key={key + 1 + folder.id}>
                    <Link to={"/FoldersList/" + folder.id}>
                            {folder.title}
                    </Link>
                    {folder.ChildrenFolder && this.getFolders(folder.childFolders, key, lvl)}
                </li>
            )}
            {texttemps.map(texttemp =>
                <li style={styles.li} className="temp" key={key + 1 + texttemp.id}>
                    <a>
                        <div onClick={() => this.getTextTemplate(texttemp.id)}>
                            {texttemp.title}
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>

            )}
        </ul>
    );
}



render() {
    let contents = this.state.loading
        ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
        : TextTemplatesEditor.getFolders(this.state.folders, this.state.texttemps, 0, 0);
    let tt = this.state.text;
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="TitleList">
                {contents}
            </div>
            <div className="App">
                <CKEditor
                    editor={ClassicEditor}
                    data={tt}
                    onInit={editor => {
                        // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
                        console.log('Editor is ready to use!', editor);
                    }}
                    onChange={(event, editor) => {
                        const data = editor.getData();
                        console.log({ event, editor, data });
                    }}
                    onBlur={editor => {
                        console.log('Blur.', editor);
                    }}
                    onFocus={editor => {
                        console.log('Focus.', editor);
                    }}
                />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение проблемы оказалось проще некуда и завязано не на код, а на логику. 
На момент `onClick` у меня уже есть `json` со всеми нужными данными, собранными в массиве. Все, что было нужно - поиск по ключу, проброшенному с `onClick`. 
Смену Url'a не нашел, но вопрос можно закрыть, т.к. основная проблема решена.